# HSM 9K- Change password of LMK component cards, change password for card with component 2 using component 1 and 3

Tags: passwords, change-password, hardware-security-module

HSM 9k production device power failed accidentally, I tried loading LMK onto the new HSM 9K. It requires three components (comp 1,2 and 3) with password. Since the configuration was done 10 years ago, the password for component 2 is lost. How can i change component 2 password using component 1 and component 3. Or if there is any other work around solution.

I tried to load the the components by uing authorization card for component 2. it accepted but the combined KCV at the end appears different from the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

That is unlucky dude. Do you have a hard copy of the components in clear text stored in a safe? Probably not.  I think you might need to create a new LMK and re-import all your keys components, zone keys etc.